# String type rig

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

How would I setup a rig so that it is only 2 bones. I am just working with a cylinder with many loop cuts. I wan to have it so that when I grab one bone at the end it affects the whole mesh. I would like to control the same way I would as a string fixed to something at one point. I can use one bone to move it.[image] Also it should not affect the size. Any tips or tricks would be great!

Comment: Not sure to understand. You mean you want to rig a rope? Something like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75673/how-to-let-a-cable-hang-so-that-it-look-realistic/75774#75774 ?

Comment: @BlendedCG: thanks for sketch, just not yet clear for me ... so its not like a hanging string or cabel. What does it mean - end bone affects whole mesh? Looks like Bendy Bones works like that, so what is wrong with them, Stretching? Sorry, I'm probably close in my box :)

Comment: Or (to move from place) where do you expect these two bones to be placed. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

### Stretch to ...

I'm not sure if I understood ... but if you want to stretch mesh, you can use for a bone **Stretch Constraint**. I use as Target Empty, but you can assing the bone or any other object.

[image]

[image]

---

### Bendy Bone

... or if you need object to bend, add [Bendy Bone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BsJ3Grq_3GM) type.

- in edit mode extrude bone down (Head) and one up (Tail)
- for selected Tail bone **Clear Parent** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

- go to pose mode, select main (middle) bone and under *Bone Properties > Bendy Bones* increase **Segment** value, for *Start Handle* set **Head** bone and for *End Handle* **Tail** bone (*Absolute* worked for me)

[image]
[image]

[image]

---

### Inverse Kinematic

but this is not achieved by two bones, here is a bone chain were end bone has Bone Constraint > **IK**, in properties panel you can **disable Stretch.**

[image]
[image]

Note: To create chain - add one bone and Subdivide <kbd>W</kbd> it. If you want to keep cylinder lay by bottom face on a floor - change **Chain Length** from zero to number of bones in chain minus one (7 in this example).

[image]

---

### Simple Deform Modifier

You didn't ask for, but since you didnt provide more info about purpose, it can fit to some cases.

[image]

Comment: I mean have one bone to control it. Like a string. You can grab one end and it will move the whole thing.

Comment: So, Inverse Kinematics?

Comment: @vkildu Yes! End bone affects whole mesh!

Comment: @BlendedCG ??? Exclamation mark means excitement or aggressivity :) Sorry I can't read the meaning from your comment and it doesnt answering my Q in OP comments. So ...

Comment: Excitement! That is what I am trying to do!

Comment: @BlendedCG - OK, good to hear (so IK version? because all of them moves in some way "whole mesh"). If the Answer worked for you consider mark A as Solved (so others can see it from main list as answered).