# Hanging object not following the rotation of the rope

Tags: modeling, animation, physics

I'm trying to animate a hanging lamp that swings in a loop, however, as you can see, the lamp itself is not following the rotation of the rope, even though I have copy rotation applied to the object and referencing the end of the rope, so it should work. I would appreciate some help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the file in case anyone wants to take a look:
[image]

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75673/how-to-let-a-cable-hang-so-that-it-look-realistic

Comment: Why have you left out the X rotation?  If you really want to do it this way,  maybe flip the mesh in Z if necessary, and include X in the copied Euler.